# How to merge two update query as a single update query in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Table1 has id and ref_id as composite primary key Below given query updates 100 columns

```
Update table1 
set contri_status = 0 
where status = 1 
  and acc_dr_status = 1 
  and contri_status = 1 
  and id = '111';
```

Below given query Updates 3 columns

```
Update table1 
set acc_dr_status = 50 
where  status = 1 
  and acc_dr_status = 1 
  and contri_status = 0 
  and id = '111' 
  and ref_id in ('1','2','3');
```

I want single query to perform above both task so tried below given query

```
Update table1 
set  contri_status = 0
   , acc_dr_status = 50    
where status = 1 
  and acc_dr_status = 1 
  and contri_status = 1 
  and id = '111' 
  and ref_id in ('1','2','3');
```

Second updated query column contri_status is depent on first query updation.
Rows modified by first are the only one going to be Modified by second query ( by first if 100 modified then by second it's going to 10 rows as i am using extra where ref_id in (...) Clause) .
Single query to update should satisfy where clause condition of both primary up date queries

Not getting proper result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used case statements to update, Hope this will work.

```
<i>UPDATE TABLE1 SET CONTRI_STATUS = (CASE WHEN CONTRI_STATUS = 1 THEN 0 ELSE CONTRI_STATUS END), 
                     ACC_DR_STATUS = (CASE WHEN CONTRI_STATUS = 0 AND REF_ID IN ('1','2','3') THEN 50 ELSE ACC_DR_STATUS END)
WHERE STATUS = 1 AND ACC_DR_STATUS = 1 AND ID = 111</i>
```

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: Per additional details provided by OP (in comments - see below; also added to question), the 2x updates are run serially with update #2 affecting only a subset of the rows affected by update #1.

```
update table1

set    contri_status = 0,

                    /* case statement limits acc_dr_status update to rows
                       limited by update #2
                    */

       acc_dr_status = case when ref_id in ('1','2','3') 
                            then 50 
                            else acc_dr_status      /* (re)set to its current value */
                       end

/* where clause finds all rows desired by update #1 */

where  status        = 1
and    acc_dr_status = 1
and    contri_status = 1
and    id            = '111'
```

Potential downsides to (re)setting the `contri_status` and `acc_dr_status` columns to their current values:

- extra writes to the log
- extra replication overhead (if replicating)
- unwanted/undesirable trigger activity (may need to recode triggers to address these scenarios)

---

NOTE: First answer based on original question and (my) assumption there was no dependencies between the two updates.

Generally speaking you could:

- combine the `where` clauses
- use `case` statements, based on the separate `where` conditions, to conditionally set the columns

One possible `update` statement using the above:

```
update table1
                    /* case statement 'when' clauses should match
                       the corresponding (distinct) where clauses 
                    */

set    contri_status = case when contri_status = 1 
                            then 0 
                            else contri_status      /* (re)set to its current value */
                       end,

       acc_dr_status = case when contri_status = 0 and ref_id in ('1','2','3') 
                            then 50 
                            else acc_dr_status      /* (re)set to its current value */
                       end

/* common where clauses */

where  status        = 1
and    acc_dr_status = 1
and    id            = '111'

/* distinct where clauses */

and    (    contri_status = 1
        or (contri_status = 0 and ref_id in ('1','2','3'))
       )
```

Same potential downsides apply re: (re)setting the `contri_status` and `acc_dr_status` columns with the same values.

Comment: In first query i am updating contri_status to 0  and in second query i am using it in where clause(updating few rows those have been updated by first query). So is  this going to help? I will be updating answer soon.Thnx

Comment: ahhh, so you're running the individual queries serially (not in parallel), with the second `update` relying on the results of the first `update`?  do you know, for a fact, that the **only** rows modified by the second `update` were also modified by the first `update`?

Comment: Let's assume update #1 updates rows #1, #2, #3 and #4; do you know for a fact that update #2 will only update a subset of these same rows?  or could update #2 also update a new row (eg, row #17 which was not modified by update #1)?

Comment: Row modified in second update were also modified by first? Yes. Rows modified by first are the only one going to be Modified by second query ( by first if 100 modified then by second it's going to 10 rows as i am using extra where ref_id in (...) Clause)

Comment: hmmm, assume **before** any updates you have a row with `contri_status=0 and ref_id='1'`; this row won't be modified by update #1, but it will be modified by update #2 ... is this scenario possible?

Comment: Second query will update the subset of first of first update 1,2,3,4 the second query will update subset of the same updated rows.

Comment: Well this scenario is possible but in second query i am updating rows based on where clause which also contain ref_id as well as id. So while updating it should consider all five where clause parameters

Comment: my hypothetical scenario assumes matches for `status`, `acc_dr_status` and `id` for all rows of interest; I'm working on a new answer thatt assumes update #2 only affects a subset of rows affecte by update #1 ... give me a few mins ...

Comment: Ok.but while updating all where clause conditions should be satisfied.

Comment: you should add these additional details about update statement dependencies to the original question as it's quite possible many folks aren't going to spend the time reading through comments to get the bigger/complete picture

Comment: Added additional details in question

Comment: I will check. Thanks

Comment: Given solution is updating only contri_status as 0 but it's not updating acc_dr_status as 50.  But it works perfectly if we make contri_status =1 in second case condition